# Call a class one minute after Eclipse is initialized

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm developing an Eclipse plugin and I would like to call a Java class some time after Eclipse is initialized i.e. 1 min. Where should I create the job that waits 1 min and calls the functions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @AmanAgnihotri But this might be happening a long time after Eclipse it initialized.

Comment: Note that it will be near impossible to make sure the code runs exactly 60 sec after startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `org.eclipse.ui.startup` extension point to specify a class which is run during Eclipse startup.

In the startup class create a `Job` (`org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.Job`) that does the work you want and use `Job.schedule(delay in milliseconds)` to schedule the job to run later.

Comment: If the timing is very important, you may want to fiddle around with startlevels to make sure your plugin starts first. Otherwise some huge 3rd party plugin could take 30s to start, causing the code to run late. See http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2009/06/10/osgi-and-start-levels/

Answer (score 0):

What does 'after eclipse is initialized' mean? Just after the framework is loaded? Right after the main window appears? Do you want for to wait for th einitial build? Each of these requires a different approach.

In the first case, in your bundles Activator create & register a `FrameworkListener` that on an `STARTED` event registers in the SWT event loop a delayed runnable.